# Creating npm module with platform specific extension on index.js

Tags: react-native, npm

I am trying to create an npm module. In my src directory I have index.ios.js and index.android.js. In my `entry` key of package.json I have `index.js`. This is resulting in import errors. Is it possible to use platform specific extensions in npm module?

Here is my package - https://github.com/Noitidart/react-native-buttonex

In summary - What should entry be if src/index.android.js src/index.ios.js

Comment: Were you able to find the solution to this problem? I have a working react-native app that I am dividing into multiple modules using `yarn workspaces`. I have created a package for images also and I am using the symlinks to resolve the images but in Android, for the images that have `ios.js` and `android.js` are not resolved. Such images are resolved in iOS but NOT in Android. So, probably some issue with the bundler for Android. Not sure how to find the issue though.

Comment: Hi @VarunGupta I think I did similar. I can't remember that that repo is still active. I wasn't happy with the solution.